Extension Html to CSS autocompletion (solnurkarim) vscode does not work
I installed extension in vscode: HTML to CSS autocompletion (author: solnurkarim).
But in file CSS, it not work - can not suggest Class/Id from HTML file.

File index.html and style.css in a folder. I already select scope is multiroot / workspace / linked file but not affect.
How to suggest Class/Id from HTML file to CSS file with that extension?
Can someone help me about that case?
Thank you so much!
